# How to highlight multiple bars in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
midwest %>% 
mutate(highlight_flag = ifelse(state == 'IL', T, F)) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = state)) +
geom_bar(aes(fill = highlight_flag))
```

The code above turns out this image[image: ggplot with one highlighted bar]

What if I not only want the first bar to be highlighted but lets say the first three(IL,IN, and MI). For example the first three in one color and the rest in a different color? All I can come up with is highlighting only one.

Thank you

Comment: Try `mutate(highlight_flag = state %in% c('IL', 'IN', 'MI'))`

Answer (score 0):

This should get you what you want

```
library(tidyverse)


midwest %>% 
mutate(highlight_flag = state %in% c('IL', 'IN', 'MI')) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = state)) +
geom_bar(aes(fill = highlight_flag))
```

[image: first three highlighted]